# Tint image and revert to normal on hover

Tags: css, image, hover, mousehover

I am currently trying to add a filter to all my images on a wordpress site that I am working on. The filter would be a blue overlay over all my images, and then once it is hovered with a mouse, the image will revert to normal.

Following various tutorials I ended up using this code:

```
img.wp-post-image {
    /* -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); */
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

img.wp-post-image:after {
    content:'';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: blue;
    opacity: 0.1;
}

img.wp-post-image:hover:after {
    opacity: 0;
    /* -webkit-filter: grayscale(0); */
    /* opacity: 0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60); */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
```

However, this doesn't' seem to be working at all. The code that I commented out (grayscale effect) worked, but the color overlay is not. Is there anything I am doing wrong, or any way I can make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Images can't receive pseudo-elements. You would need to wrap each image and place an overlay on the wrapper.

Comment: @Paulie_D Hmm, since I am using a wordpress template, would I be able to still create a class to wrap each of the images?

Comment: I'n not up on WP. Do you really need an overlay though? Perhaps a combination of `filters` might be better....you can use more than one at a time.

Comment: @Paulie_D my real goal was to make a blue gradient over all the images on the site. With webkit filters, I wasn't able to achieve that standard color on all the images. I'm not entirely sure if I am missing some sort of specific code to do that.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/g8g7rfez/ ?

Comment: @MrLister Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. However, I want all my pictures to have a specific blue color overlay. With webkit filters, all the images don't acquire a 'uniform' design.

Comment: In that case, you will need to do as Paulie_D says and use a container.

Comment: @MrLister yeah, you are right. I know how to do that with custom websites, but with wordpress it's a whole different story.